# Call a MySQL JSON function passing in a path representing a property that is a number

Tags: mysql, json

I have a JSON block where a property is a number. For example `{"123": "1"}`. But I can't seem to get it to work with MySQL's *JSON_CONTAINS* function. I also tried the *JSON_CONTAINS_PATH* function with the same result.

The following works:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS('{"a": 1}', '1', '$.a');
```

But the following gives me an error:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS('{"123": 1}', '1', '$.123');
```

> Query Error: Error: ER_INVALID_JSON_PATH: Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 5.

I've gone over the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains, but the examples provided are only using strings as properties.

There must be a way to accomplish this. I'm using MySQL 8.0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following double-quote the key name:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS('{"123": 1}', '1', '$."123"');
```

> For paths used in MySQL JSON functions, the scope is always the document being searched or otherwise operated on, represented by a leading $ character. Path legs are separated by period characters (.). Cells in arrays are represented by `[N]`, where `N` is a non-negative integer. Names of keys must be double-quoted strings or valid ECMAScript identifiers (see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6).
>
> **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax

---

> A period followed by a key name names the member in an object with the given key. The key name must be specified within double quotation marks if the name without quotes is not legal within path expressions (for example, if it contains a space).
>
> **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I knew it would be something simple. I wish the MySQL documentation would have had at least one example of this. Would have saved me some time ;)